# Intel AX200 Bluetooth not working in Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

Tags: drivers, bluetooth, support

### I'm new to Ubuntu.

Hello everyone , I did a fresh install, next to Windows 11. Fast-boot and hibernate are disabled on Windows. Fast-boot disabled from BIOS-UEFI.
I also did all the updates of the system, but the Bluetooth still does not work. Anyone have any ideas?

### What I've tried:

1. [Here.](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=340234)
2. [Cannot run .deb file with `sudo dpkg -i`](https://www.reddit.com/r/linux4noobs/comments/u8m5f2/bluetooth_disabled_after_upgrade_to_ubuntu_2204/)
3. I also tried the AX200 Linux driver from Intel's web-site:
   "`iwlwifi-cc-a0-46.ucode`"

> `inxi -Fxxxz`

```
System:
  Kernel: 5.15.0-46-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 11.2.0
    Desktop: GNOME 42.2 tk: GTK 3.24.33 wm: gnome-shell dm: GDM3 42.0
    Distro: Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)
Machine:
  Type: Desktop System: ASUS product: N/A v: N/A serial: <superuser required>
  Mobo: ASUSTeK model: ROG STRIX B550-E GAMING v: Rev X.0x
    serial: <superuser required> UEFI: American Megatrends v: 2803
    date: 04/28/2022
CPU:
  Info: 6-core model: AMD Ryzen 5 5600X bits: 64 type: MT MCP smt: enabled
    arch: Zen 3 rev: 0 cache: L1: 384 KiB L2: 3 MiB L3: 32 MiB
  Speed (MHz): avg: 2997 high: 3600 min/max: 2200/4650 boost: enabled
    cores: 1: 2879 2: 2877 3: 2880 4: 3600 5: 2876 6: 2879 7: 2870 8: 2878
    9: 2879 10: 3599 11: 2877 12: 2876 bogomips: 88810
  Flags: avx avx2 ht lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 sse4a ssse3 svm
Graphics:
  Device-1: NVIDIA GM206 [GeForce GTX 960] vendor: eVga.com. driver: nvidia
    v: 515.65.01 pcie: speed: 8 GT/s lanes: 16 ports: active: none
    off: HDMI-A-1 empty: DP-1, DP-2, DP-3, DVI-I-1 bus-ID: 07:00.0
    chip-ID: 10de:1401 class-ID: 0300
  Display: x11 server: X.Org v: 1.21.1.3 compositor: gnome-shell driver: X:
    loaded: nvidia unloaded: fbdev,modesetting,nouveau,vesa gpu: nvidia
    display-ID: :1 screens: 1
  Screen-1: 0 s-res: 1920x1080 s-dpi: 92 s-size: 530x301mm (20.9x11.9")
    s-diag: 610mm (24")
  Monitor-1: HDMI-0 res: 1920x1080 dpi: 93 size: 527x296mm (20.7x11.7")
    diag: 604mm (23.8")
  OpenGL: renderer: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 960/PCIe/SSE2
    v: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 515.65.01 direct render: Yes
Audio:
  Device-1: NVIDIA GM206 High Definition Audio vendor: eVga.com.
    driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel pcie: speed: 8 GT/s lanes: 16
    bus-ID: 07:00.1 chip-ID: 10de:0fba class-ID: 0403
  Device-2: AMD Starship/Matisse HD Audio vendor: ASUSTeK
    driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel pcie: speed: 16 GT/s lanes: 16
    bus-ID: 09:00.4 chip-ID: 1022:1487 class-ID: 0403
  Sound Server-1: ALSA v: k5.15.0-46-generic running: yes
  Sound Server-2: PulseAudio v: 15.99.1 running: yes
  Sound Server-3: PipeWire v: 0.3.48 running: yes
Network:
  Device-1: Intel Wi-Fi 6 AX200 driver: iwlwifi v: kernel pcie: speed: 5 GT/s
    lanes: 1 bus-ID: 05:00.0 chip-ID: 8086:2723 class-ID: 0280
  IF: wlp5s0 state: up mac: <filter>
  Device-2: Intel Ethernet I225-V vendor: ASUSTeK driver: igc v: kernel
    pcie: speed: 5 GT/s lanes: 1 port: N/A bus-ID: 06:00.0 chip-ID: 8086:15f3
    class-ID: 0200
  IF: enp6s0 state: down mac: <filter>
  IF-ID-1: virbr0 state: down mac: <filter>
Drives:
  Local Storage: total: 931.51 GiB used: 29.18 GiB (3.1%)
  ID-1: /dev/nvme0n1 vendor: PNY model: CS3030 1TB SSD size: 931.51 GiB
    speed: 31.6 Gb/s lanes: 4 type: SSD serial: <filter> rev: CS303226
    temp: 30.9 C scheme: GPT
Partition:
  ID-1: / size: 95.56 GiB used: 29.15 GiB (30.5%) fs: ext4
    dev: /dev/nvme0n1p2
  ID-2: /boot/efi size: 96 MiB used: 32.3 MiB (33.6%) fs: vfat
    dev: /dev/nvme0n1p1
Swap:
  Alert: No swap data was found.
Sensors:
  System Temperatures: cpu: N/A mobo: N/A gpu: nvidia temp: 54 C
  Fan Speeds (RPM): N/A gpu: nvidia fan: 0%
Info:
  Processes: 336 Uptime: 5m wakeups: 0 Memory: 15.54 GiB
  used: 1.94 GiB (12.5%) Init: systemd v: 249 runlevel: 5 Compilers: gcc: N/A
  Packages: 1831 apt: 1806 snap: 25 Shell: Bash v: 5.1.16
  running-in: gnome-terminal inxi: 3.3.13
```

> `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3`

```
05:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX200 [8086:2723] (rev 1a)
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX200NGW [8086:0084]
Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
Kernel modules: iwlwifi
```

> `lsusb`

```
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 05e3:0610 Genesys Logic, Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 05e3:0610 Genesys Logic, Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0b05:18f3 ASUSTek Computer, Inc. AURA LED Controller
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 046d:c548 Logitech, Inc. USB Receiver
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

> `dpkg --list | egrep -i blue`

```
ii  bluetooth                                  5.64-0ubuntu1                           all          Bluetooth support (metapackage)
ii  bluez                                      5.64-0ubuntu1                           amd64        Bluetooth tools and daemons
ii  bluez-cups                                 5.64-0ubuntu1                           amd64        Bluetooth printer driver for CUPS
ii  bluez-firmware                             1.2-7                                   all          Firmware for Bluetooth devices
ii  bluez-hcidump                              5.64-0ubuntu1                           amd64        Analyses Bluetooth HCI packets
ii  bluez-obexd                                5.64-0ubuntu1                           amd64        bluez obex daemon
ii  bluez-tools                                2.0~20170911.0.7cb788c-4                amd64        Set of tools to manage Bluetooth devices for linux
ii  gir1.2-gnomebluetooth-3.0:amd64            42.0-5                                  amd64        Introspection data for GnomeBluetooth
ii  gnome-bluetooth-3-common                   42.0-5                                  all          GNOME Bluetooth 3 common files
ii  gnome-bluetooth-common                     3.34.5-8                                all          GNOME Bluetooth common files
ii  libbluetooth3:amd64                        5.64-0ubuntu1                           amd64        Library to use the BlueZ Linux Bluetooth stack
ii  libgnome-bluetooth-3.0-13:amd64            42.0-5                                  amd64        GNOME Bluetooth 3 support library
ii  libgnome-bluetooth13:amd64                 3.34.5-8                                amd64        GNOME Bluetooth tools - support library
ii  pulseaudio-module-bluetooth                1:15.99.1+dfsg1-1ubuntu1                amd64        Bluetooth module for PulseAudio sound server
```

---

### OK, this is so weird.

I turned off the computer and went to sleep. I had also turned off the power supply with the switch.
I ran the following commands;

`systemctl status bluetooth.service`

```
○ bluetooth.service
     Loaded: masked (Reason: Unit bluetooth.service is masked.)
     Active: inactive (dead)
```

---

`systemctl start bluetooth.service`

```
Failed to start bluetooth.service: Unit bluetooth.service is masked.
```

---

`systemctl enable bluetooth.service`

```
Synchronizing state of bluetooth.service with SysV service script with /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install.
Executing: /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install enable bluetooth
Failed to enable unit: Unit file /etc/systemd/system/bluetooth.service is masked.
```

---

`systemctl status x11-common`

```
○ x11-common.service
     Loaded: masked (Reason: Unit x11-common.service is masked.)
     Active: inactive (dead)
```

---

`systemctl unmask bluetooth.service`

```
Removed /etc/systemd/system/bluetooth.service.
```

---

`systemctl start bluetooth.service`

```
Empty
```

---

`systemctl status bluetooth.service`

```
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor pre>
     Active: active (running) since Mon 2022-08-22 11:55:19 +03; 12s ago
       Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
   Main PID: 5264 (bluetoothd)
     Status: "Running"
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 19002)
     Memory: 2.0M
        CPU: 37ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
             └─5264 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

August 22 11:55:19 ubuntu bluetoothd[5264]: Starting SDP server
August 22 11:55:19 ubuntu bluetoothd[5264]: Bluetooth management interface 1.21 in>
August 22 11:55:19 ubuntu bluetoothd[5264]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.80 path>
August 22 11:55:19 ubuntu bluetoothd[5264]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.80 path>
August 22 11:55:19 ubuntu bluetoothd[5264]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.80 path>
August 22 11:55:19 ubuntu bluetoothd[5264]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.80 path>
August 22 11:55:19 ubuntu bluetoothd[5264]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.80 path>
August 22 11:55:19 ubuntu bluetoothd[5264]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.80 path>
August 22 11:55:19 ubuntu bluetoothd[5264]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.80 path>
August 22 11:55:19 ubuntu bluetoothd[5264]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.80 path>
```

In my previous attempts, the `systemctl unmask bluetooth.service` and `systemctl start bluetooth.service` commands did not work. But it's running now.

### Question:

**Now, I have a question, should `bluetooth.service` stay in `unmask` state or not? What is the correct way to do this?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The service should be unmasked if you want it to be working.

Answer (score 1):

I got that same Bluetooth hardware and got this `no default devices` error.
`systemctl reboot` did not fix it, but by doing a `systemctl poweroff` fixed the problem when I then started up the computer (ASUS MINIPC PN50) again!